# What library is cloud9 gui written in?

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, cloud9-ide

I cannot find any information abut the library, that cloud9 ui is written in. 
I have heard that it uses ui.ajax.org, but it looks far better than ui.ajax.org examples. Is it true or is it using another library?

Comment: where the close votes come from? it is in Q&A style and it will not start any debate ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the source code yourself :

https://github.com/ajaxorg ,

and yes ajax.org and cloud9 seems to be made by the same guys.